# Dynamic column names in a postgres crosstab query

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I am trying to pivot the data in a query in postgres. The query I am currently using is as follows

```
SELECT
  product_number,
  month,
  sum(quantity)
FROM forecasts
WHERE date_trunc('month', extract_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date)
GROUP BY product_number, month
ORDER BY product_number, month;
```

The output of the query is something like what is shown below where each product will have 13 months of data.

```
+--------+------------+----------+
| Number |   Month    | Quantity |
+--------+------------+----------+
|      1 | 2016-10-01 |     7592 |
|      1 | 2016-11-01 |     6796 |
|      1 | 2016-12-01 |     6512 |
|      1 | 2017-01-01 |     6160 |
|      1 | 2017-02-01 |     6475 |
|      1 | 2017-03-01 |     6016 |
|      1 | 2017-04-01 |     6616 |
|      1 | 2017-05-01 |     6536 |
|      1 | 2017-06-01 |     6256 |
|      1 | 2017-07-01 |     6300 |
|      1 | 2017-08-01 |     5980 |
|      1 | 2017-09-01 |     5872 |
|      1 | 2017-10-01 |     5824 |
+--------+------------+----------+
```

I am trying to pivot the data so that it looks something like

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+
| Number | 2016-10-1 | 2016-11-1 | 2016-12-1 | 2017-1-1 | ... |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+
| 1      |       100 |       100 |       200 |      250 | ... |
| ...    |           |           |           |          |     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----+
```

Where all the data for each product is shown in a row for the 13 months.

I tried using a basic crosstab query

```
SELECT *
FROM
crosstab('SELECT product_number, month::TEXT, sum(quantity)
   FROM forecasts
   WHERE date_trunc(''month'', extract_date) = date_trunc(''month'', ''2016-10-1''::DATE)
   GROUP BY product_number, month
   ORDER BY product_number, month')
    As mthreport(product_number text, m0 DATE, m1 DATE, m2 DATE,
        m3 DATE, m4 DATE, m5 DATE, m6 DATE,
        m7 DATE, m8 DATE, m9 DATE, m10 DATE,
        m11 DATE, m12 DATE, m13 DATE)
```

But I get the following error

```
ERROR: invalid return type Detail: SQL rowid datatype does not match return rowid datatype.
```

If the column name were set in the crosstab i.e. if I could define and put the names into the crosstab output this works, but since the dates keep changing I am not sure how to define them

I think I missing something very basic here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: m1 int, m2 int.... not date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping, i have understood your problem correctly.

Column m1, m2 .. m13 are not of date type. These columns will contain sum of quantity. So, data type will be same as sum(quantity).

I think below query will solve your problem

```
SELECT *
FROM
 crosstab($$SELECT product_number, month, sum(quantity)::bigint
   FROM forecasts
   GROUP BY product_number, month
   ORDER BY product_number, month$$)
    As mthreport(product_number int, m0 bigint, m1 bigint, m2 bigint,
        m3 bigint, m4 bigint, m5 bigint, m6 bigint,
        m7 bigint, m8 bigint, m9 bigint, m10 bigint,
        m11 bigint, m12 bigint , m13 bigint)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I seem to have misunderstood the documentation. Changing the type to numeric fixed it.